# Forbidden Reddit API call - Search within subreddit

Tags: python, python-requests, reddit

I'm making an API call to the Reddit API and receiving a response of:

```
{'message': 'Forbidden', 'error': 403}
```

My question is why?  I get the JSON as expected when I visit this URL in the browser: https://www.reddit.com/r/Charlottesville/search.json?q=food&restrict_sr=on

I have set up my auth and everything and have made many successful API requests. My headers are correct.
When I run the following code I get the 'forbidden' response:

```
#### Search within Subreddit

res = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/Charlottesville/search.json?q=food&restrict_sr=on',
                   headers=headers)

print(res.json())
```

Comment: The requests [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) shows passing query arguments as a `params=` arg, not hardcoding them directly in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was a very simple one. A properly authenticated request should be made to `oauth.reddit.com` so my properly formatted URL is:

```
https://oauth.reddit.com/r/Charlottesville/search.json?q=food&restrict_sr=on
```

and it works!